# Invoking guard from Rake task suppresses the output

Tags: ruby, command-line, rake, guard

I am trying to place the command to invoke tests inside a Rakefile like so:

```
desc 'Start tests'
task :test do
  %x{ bundle exec guard --clear }
end
```

Though the command: `bundle exec guard --clear` runs perfectly otherwise; test output seems to be suppressed when invoked it through the Rake task. Only notifications such as running spec or starting Guard is being outputted.

*Note: I know the tests are indeed working as I have another notification system through tmux pane colours.*

I think, something is wrong with the way I am building the Rake tasks? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the %x waits until the command finishes before printing any output.

Example:

```
puts %x{ sleep 1; echo "hello"; sleep 2; echo "world"; }
```

(This will not show any output until it finishes - then it shows everything at once.)

Example 2:

```
puts %x{ echo "hello"; sleep 100; }
```

(This will not show anything until 100 seconds have passed).

What you want is:

```
Kernel.system("bundle exec guard --clear")
```

or

```
Kernel.system(%w(bundle exec guard --clear))
```

Comment: Do you mean to say that this keeps printing the output before the command completes? I am sorry I don't really remember which project I was using this to test it now.